# JAX-WS Exception handling

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, exception, jax-ws

Exception Handling in java based we services JAX-WS.

I want to create user defined exception for my web services that I have written in JAX-WS (java based web services).

The simple conventional way is to create a `simpleException` class which must extend `Exception` class then use it any where with the `throw` key word.

Whether this same process is valid on Web services or is there any special way available to handle exceptions in web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use exceptions in case of calling web services is the same as you have in java rmi and others(the same as in pure java). In case you use code first wsdl gen will generate exception classes, so client will be able to differentiate your custom exceptions(the only thing is this would be a custom exception hierarchy).